How do you access the custom HttpMessageHandlers assigned to an HttpClient?
I'm building an HttpClient adapter for a connection to E*Trade. This HttpClient requires a custom message handler that needs to know things about the connection for OAuth. Things like the access token, the consumer key, consumer secret and token secret, etc.
My configuration of this arrangement looks like this:
// Configure the E*Trade adapter.
serviceCollection
    .AddHttpClient<ETradeAdapter>(httpClient => httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress, UriKind.Absolute))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<ETradeMessageHandler>();

At run-time, I collect the OAuth parameters based on the user's identity and try to plug them into the E*Trade message handler. How do I find the message adapters associated with my HttpClient when I'm using this pattern so that I can set these parameters?
Edit: What I want to do can be accomplished with this, but it appears clumsy and I feel there just must be a better way:
        var eTradeMessageHandler = this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ETradeMessageHandler>();
        eTradeMessageHandler.AccessToken = "some token";
        eTradeMessageHandler.TokenSecret = "some secret";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(eTradeMessageHandler);
        var eTradeHttpAdapter = new ETradeAdapter(httpClient);


What is clumsy about your existing code?

It bypasses Dependency Injection by creating HttpClient and ETradeAdapter on-the-fly.

In addition, it appears to defeat the whole purpose of using an IHttpClientFactory in the first place: to minimize the number of HttpClients that you create.

You can't without using reflection: it's the internal _handler field of HttpMessageInvoker, the base class for HttpClient.
See here the code for HttpMessageInvoker: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpMessageInvoker.cs

I don't understand why this is so difficult. The HttpMessageHandler appears to be the natural place where I'd want to attach a bearer token and handle a 401 error by refreshing the tokens. How are we supposed to communicate tokens or credentials to the handler if we can't access it?

You can do it by attaching another handler on top of the existing one. You can also pass the primary on the constructor, if you need it to be the first. What you are asking for is very common.

How do you attach another handler on top of the existing one if you don't have access to the existing one? Some code examples would help me understand what you're suggesting here.

It’s AddHttpMessageHandler, when you register the HttpClient

You do not understand the issue. I don't have the E*Trade credentials when the application initializes the DI container. I need a mechanism to pass the OAuth credentials to the HTTP Message Handler after the application has started.

There are overloads to AddHttpClient that take an IServiceProvider. If you use them, at runtime, when setting the properties to the HttpClient, you can extract the values you want from the service provider (like, with some Options), and set them on the HttpClient. Would this work?

The trick to getting this to work is the Options property of the HttpRequestMessage. It's basically a dictionary for communicating with the message handler. I created a singleton token handler which contained a dictionary of all the credentials (tokens and secrets) for all the OAuth sessions I was managing with the host web service, then I passed the key to the credentials in the Options. The message handler can pull this key out of the request and look up the credentials in the singleton token manager.
